# Convert value stored as hex to date

Tags: c#, date, hex

I have data stored in a file in HEX format and I know some examples of what the corresponding date should be. 
However I am unable to determine how to calculate it.

```
83 61 94     04/08/2015
83 61 75     16/07/2015
83 61 97     07/08/2015
83  0 135    01/01/1999
83 51 64     08/10/2012
```

I don't know how the date was encoded originally and have no way of finding out as the data file is old and no longer supported by anyone.

any suggestions as to how to convert the hex to the corresponding date??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
2015-08-04 - **94** days = 2015-05-02
2015-07-16 - **75** days = 2015-05-02
2015-08-07 - **97** days = 2015-05-02
```

So the third byte, in its "hexadecimal form" must have to do with the "number of days" and 2015-05-02 should be encoded as 83 61 00 I guess. However you should provide some more examples of other dates with different years so as to understand the other bytes.

EDIT: You new data can tell the following
83 51 64 --> 2012-10-08 - ** 64 ** days = 2012-08-05 (83 51 00) 
83 01 35 --> 1999-01-01 - **83** days = 1998-11-27 (83 01 00)

61 - 51 = 10, and there are 1000 days between 2012-08-05 and 2015-05-02 (83 61 00), that means, the second "byte" also give us "days" but with a x100 multiplier.

Try it on the second case (1998-11-27). There are 6000 thousand days from that date to 2015-05-02 (83 61 00). 61-01 = 60 * 100.

I believe your formula should be something like:
Date in "hex" (AA BB CC)

Date = (AA * 1000 + BB * 100 + CC) days + Date_0

And I let you calculate yourself Date_0 as you can use any of the date examples that you have provided.

Note I am assuming AA is multiplied by 1000 as you have not provided any example where the first byte was changed.

Comment: 83 51 64 -   08/10/2012

Comment: 83  0 135 -   01/01/1999

Comment: Can you provide an example with the oldest date you can input? I am not totally sure my assumption of multiplying by 1000 is OK.

Comment: According to my formula, Date_0 = 1788/02/01

Comment: unfortunately the oldest sample I have is the 1999 example

Comment: Well, you could try if my formula works anyway! Try it with some other dates and see if it works!